# <h21> custom header shows up fine in Chrome & FireFox but not IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

Q: Why is the following header showing up differently in IE9 as what I would expect in Chrome/Firefox (this is being called from an mvc3/razor/css?

```
h21 
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
}

<h21>Custom Defined Header as &lt;h21&gt;</h21>
```

Per the following screenshot: Top is Chrome & Firefox (as expected) and the bottom is IE9.

[image]

Comment: I am no longer surprised that IE doesn't render things the same as Chrome/Firefox would. Just another example.

Comment: There is no h21 tag so IE doesn't have to render it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged the question 'html5', but the fact is that `<h21>` is not an HTML element, and that includes HTML5.

Even under the permissive HTML5 rules, browsers are not required to render anything that isn't a recognised element. The fact that some browsers do render it does not make it any more valid.

The point of HTML5 is not to make infinite new elements available. Yes they have added quite a number of elements to the spec, but they've selected them carefully to help you give the document semantic meaning - ie the tags become hints to help a search engine or similar bot decipher what the page is about. Adding your own arbitrary tags will not achieve this.

You'd be far better off sticking with the existing tags, and giving them a class to define how they should be rendered.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you on HTML5.  Thought there might be some HTML5 around this particular item.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: So, what would be the best tag a div?

Comment: @Jacquo - it depends on the context. I don't know what you were intending with `<h21>`. There are `<header>` and `<hgroup>` tags, which are intended for extending the basic `<h1>` to `<h6>`. See http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/ for more info.

Answer (score 5):

Don't invent your own tags. Stick to using HTML instead.

While you can persuade most browsers to render (and apply CSS to) unknown elements, they are meaningless to most clients (including screen readers and search engine indexing bots) and generate a lot of noise when you use a validator for basic QA.

That said, you can persuade IE to apply CSS to an unknown element by using JS to generate an element of that type (`document.createElement('h21');`).

Answer (score 0):

There are only the tags `<h1>` to `<h6>`, there is no tag, which is named `<h21>`. Browsers like Chrome and Firefox ignores your errors and displays your website properly anyway.

Comment: This was said twice 13 hours before your post - what new info does your post bring to the table?